# A box Contains 7 red and 6 green ball

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A box Contains $7$ red and $6$ green balls. If $2$ balls are drawn from the box,
 What is the probability of getting:

a. Both Green

b. $1$ red and $1$ green.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please make effort before asking question, and tell us what your trouble.

Answer (score 3):

a. $\dfrac{{}^7C{}_0\times {}^6C{}_2}{{}^{13}C{}_2}$

b. $\dfrac{{}^7C{}_1\times {}^6C{}_1}{{}^{13}C{}_2}$

Answer (score 0):

The probability of drawing two green balls from the box would be $\frac{6}{13}\cdot\frac{5}{12}=\frac{5}{26}$ because the probability of drawing a green ball is $\frac{6}{13}$. After we've drawn a green ball, the probability of drawing another green ball will be that probability times the probability of drawing a green ball given the fact that there is now fewer balls in the box: $\frac{6}{13}\cdot\frac{5}{12}$.

You use the same logic for getting a red ball and a green ball: $\frac{7}{13}\cdot\frac{6}{12}=\frac{7}{26}$.